# Disable tab click on some editors in table

Tags: tabulator

Would it be possible to disable "Tab" events on specific columns.

My current table has 4 input, 1 of which is a dropdown for status and the rest are text fields.

The scenario is that the users are inputting data on the text fields but they don't want the dropdown to open up on the next row and just proceed on the next text field.

Comment: Is the dropdown values static with only few possible values or is it dynamic?

Comment: Static values on the status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values are static, you could use a custom editor to do your work.

Working Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/disable-tab-some-editors-ud5vit?file=/src/index.js

In the demo, I used the column "Status" as a select field with three possible values. Tab won't make dropdown appear by default.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Interesting, so you are technically overriding the behavior when the select is clicked. I guess the downside is needing it to be click twice and the tab still selects it but not open it up which should be good enough. Thanks will consider this approach

Comment: Yeah. I tried the conventional way without overriding but I couldn't achieve your required functionality. So, I overrode the select editor. Tbh I don't think we could achieve your need without overriding as far as I know. If you find a better way, do mention. Thanks!